# How to return specific rows that meets the set criteria via excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this data and I am tracking the consecutive and multiple occurrence of defect code.
Consecutive defect code are those that appear under the same area and line consecutively.
Multiple are those defect code that appear 3 times or more (even if not conscutive)
under the same area and line.

```
Area    Line    Lot #           Date              Code  Description
Assy    Line1   LOT000000001    10/3/2013 13:31   5c    Vibration fail
Assy    Line12  LOT000000002    10/3/2013 13:25   5g    Key Malfunction
Labl    Line2   LOT000000003    10/3/2013 13:08   5a    No charge
Dice    Line1   LOT000000004    10/3/2013 13:03   5b    System Fail
Dice    Line2   LOT000000005    10/3/2013 13:09   3j    Sofwware fail
Dice    Line3   LOT000000006    10/3/2013 13:29   5d    No display
Circ    Line1   LOT000000007    10/3/2013 13:25   3n    Short
Circ    Line1   LOT000000008    10/3/2013 13:38   3n    Short
Circ    Line10  LOT000000009    10/3/2013 13:26   3n    Short
Circ    Line12  LOT000000010    10/3/2013 13:30   3n    Short
Circ    Line2   LOT000000011    10/3/2013 13:02   3n    Short
Circ    Line3   LOT000000012    10/3/2013 13:15   3n    Short
Circ    Line7   LOT000000013    10/3/2013 13:24   3n    Short
Circ    LineA   LOT000000014    10/3/2013 13:10   3o    Open
Circ    LineA   LOT000000015    10/3/2013 13:14   3n    Short
Circ    LineA   LOT000000016    10/3/2013 13:46   3c    High Res
Circ    LineA   LOT000000017    10/3/2013 13:47   3n    Short
Circ    LineA   LOT000000018    10/3/2013 13:50   3o    Open
Circ    LineA   LOT000000019    10/3/2013 13:51   3n    Short
Circ    LineA   LOT000000020    10/3/2013 13:55   3b    Low Res
OSTS    Line1   LOT000000021    10/3/2013 13:48   3b    Low Res
OSTS    Line1   LOT000000022    10/3/2013 13:50   3f    No Trace
OSTS    Line11  LOT000000023    10/3/2013 13:06   3a    No Signal
OSTS    Line2   LOT000000024    10/3/2013 13:24   3a    No Signal
```

In this case, my expected result would be:

```
Circ    Line1   LOT000000007    10/3/2013 13:25   3n    Short
Circ    Line1   LOT000000008    10/3/2013 13:38   3n    Short
```

for the consecutive occurrence.

and this for the multiple occurrence.

```
Circ    LineA   LOT000000015    10/3/2013 13:14   3n    Short
Circ    LineA   LOT000000017    10/3/2013 13:47   3n    Short
Circ    LineA   LOT000000019    10/3/2013 13:51   3n    Short
```

So the original data is on Sheet1 and I want the result transferred in Sheet2 with the same header.
 What I did is to pass the original data into an array and then iterate through it.
 I am not getting what I want though. The code is long so I did not bother to post.

And I think is it easier to make a new code than to debug mine.
 Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.
 If you still have questions, just fire it away.

Comment: How you want the data to appear as in Sheet2 ?

Comment: @Santosh consecutively with the same header as the original data. The purpose is to track and consolidate all consecutive and multiple occurences of defect code.

Comment: I don't understand your first example... How is `Cire Line1` and `Circ Line1` together for the consecutive occurrence? or is `Cire` a typo?

Comment: @sid yes, its a typo. it should be `Circ`. thanks.

Comment: Your objective is to just identify the defect right? If yes then a formula would do?

Comment: @sid no, i need to transfer the data as mentioned above to another sheet so i will have another database consisting of data that meet the consecutive and multiple criteria only. So the the result would be the five lines above copied on Sheet2 with the same headear Area,line,Lot# etc...

Comment: Hmm... How 5? and not 7? See this image. http://wikisend.com/download/530866/2.png Am I missing something?

Comment: ah 3o will not meet the criteria. it is not conscutive, and it is not multiple since it does not occur 3 times or more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38762/discussion-between-l42-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: So could you update your above post to confirm that multiple mean 3 or more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also in favor of using formulas for this and the screenshot that I gave in the comments in your post was derived using formulas. However since you wanted a VBA code, Here it is.

Let's say, your sheet looks like this

[image]

**Logic:**

1. Find Last Row of Sheet1
2. Insert the formula `=A2&B2&D2&F2` in Col H
3. Insert the formula `=IF(H2=H3,"YES",IF(H2=H1,"YES",""))` in Col I
4. Insert the formula `=IF(AND(I2="",COUNTIF(H:H,H2)>2),"YES" & H2,"")` in Col J

   - The objective to achieve this

   [image]
5. Next Create 2 Sheets for output. Let's output the consecutive records to `Consecutive` Sheet and multiple records to `Multiple` sheets
6. Filter the `Col I` for `Yes` and move them to `Consecutive` sheet
7. Filter the `Col J` for `Non Blanks` and move them to `Multiple` sheet
8. Sort the data in `Multiple` sheet based on Col J
9. Delete Columns `H:J` from all sheets

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsConsc As Worksheet, wsMulti As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the releavnt sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> To create Consecutive and Multi sheets, delete existing ones if appl
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consecutive").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Multi").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Create new sheets for output
    Set wsConsc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add: wsConsc.Name = "Consecutive"
    Set wsMulti = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add: wsMulti.Name = "Multi"

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Columns("H:J").ClearContents

        .Range("H2:H" & lRow).Formula = "=A2&B2&D2&F2"
        .Range("I2:I" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(H2=H3,""YES"",IF(H2=H1,""YES"",""""))"
        .Range("J2:J" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(AND(I2="""",COUNTIF(H:H,H2)>2),""YES"" & H2,"""")"

        .Range("H2:J" & lRow).Value = .Range("H2:J" & lRow).Value

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With .Range("I1:I" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=YES"
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
            wsConsc.Rows(1)
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With .Range("J1:J" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
            wsMulti.Rows(1)

            wsMulti.Columns("A:J").Sort Key1:=wsMulti.Range("J2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
            OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        .Columns("H:J").ClearContents
        wsConsc.Columns("H:J").ClearContents
        wsMulti.Columns("H:J").ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Works great! :) i just changed the formula in Col I to this `=IF(COUNTIF(H:H,H2)<3,IF(H2=H3,"YES",IF(H2=H1,"YES","")),"")` This is to get the defect code that is both multiple and consecutive to Multi sheet. Thanks Sid.

Answer (score 1):

formula in `I2`= `=A2&B2&G2`
formula in `J2`= `=COUNTIF($I$2:$I$25,I2)`
formula in `K2`= `=I2=I3`
formula in `L2`= `=IF(OR(K2,J2>=3,K1),"Copy","Do not copy")`

Filter the data in `column L` and copy to desired sheet.

[image]

Comment: thanks Santosh, i'll try to code a vba with this. it will surely get me moving a bit :D